# Popup disables navigation menu in Elementor Pro

Tags: menu, popup, elementor, popupmenu

I'm using elementor pro to design a website, and the navigation menu works fine without popups, but I want to put an age gate on the site, and when the pop-up is active, the navigation menu no longer expands or functions.

Has anybody else run into this? I have no clue where to continue troubleshooting from.

The popup itself functions fine, but once closed, the normal navigation menu no longer works. I've disabled the popup and the navigation works normally again. I've left the popup disabled for now.